# Error creating branch or tag in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Ever since upgrading to SVN 1.8 (on VisualSVN Server 2.6.2), whenever I try to create a branch (or a tag), I get this error :

> Could not COPY /svn/[path] due to a failed precondition on the source
>   (e.g. locks).  [424, #0]
>
> An error occurred on another resource, preventing the requested
>   operation on this resource.  [424, #0]

This only happens in a single repository - I have upgraded two more and they work flawlessly, ie: we are able to branch and tag normally. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Did you _upgrade_ the repository format? `svnadmin upgrade REPO_PATH`.

Comment: Yes, it was done by the VisualSVN installer but I did it manually afterward, just to be safe.

Comment: try doing an svn cleanup?

Comment: @Krashlog VisualSVN Server installed does not automatically update your repositories format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the error message was right about having a lock somewhere in the trunk.

Strangely enough, the lock wasn't visible to my client (TortoiseSVN) - neither `Release Lock` nor the `Cleanup` command reported it. I tried `svnadmin lslocks` and lo and behold, it listed a single xml config file locked in... January 2012.

Looks like the upgrade from SVN 1.6 to 1.8 somehow caused this ancient lock to come back. Using `svnadmin rmlocks` on that file solved the problem and branching / tagging is no longer failing. Just to make sure I tried locking / unlocking the file through TortoiseSVN and everything works normally now, ie: locks get listed, etc.

Sorry I can't offer a more logical explanation for this problem, except that maybe old versions of locks didn't get upgraded properly, and / or TortoiseSVN doesn't handle upgraded locks correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55306) that has been introduced in Apache HTTP Server
2.2.25 mod_dav module. The workaround for this bug is going to be available in the next VisualSVN
Server patch release; it will be released in the same time as Apache Subversion 1.8.3.

As a possible workaround you can tag a branch with `svn copy` using
[`file://`](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/basic/in-action/#svn.advanced.reposurls) protocol on the server machine (in other words, use local
URL with `file://` protocol). It's not recommended since
requires full access to the server machine and repository, only server
administrator should perform the action.